# Laravel: how to set a custom column with conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, api, laravel, eloquent

Is possible with pure Eloquent uses, without php loops, add in a select statement a custom column and value to a relation just if the relation exists? I think that I don't know how to explain better, but I will try...

The json result from my current query(eloquent) is the following json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 3,
        "category_id": 2,
        "city_id": 1,
        "title": "Outro teste",
        "body": "999999 sdf23asd f23asd32f1 as321f32as1d f1sdf",
        "image_path": "",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "expires_at": "2015-03-20 04:44:53",
        "popularity": 0,
        "is_favorite": "true",
        "category": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Categoria 2",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "color": "#0F0",
            "parent_id": null,
            "type": "INTEREST",
            "slug": "categoria-2",
            "icon_path": null
        },
        "favorite": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 3,
        "category_id": 3,
        "city_id": 1,
        "title": "Interesse de Teste 2",
        "body": "2321fads132f123d sf 12sdf sd132",
        "image_path": "",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "expires_at": "2015-03-21 02:34:53",
        "popularity": 0,
        "is_favorite": "true",
        "category": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Subcategoria 1",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "color": "#00F",
            "parent_id": 1,
            "type": "INTEREST",
            "slug": "subcategoria-1",
            "icon_path": null
        },
        "favorite": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 3,
                "favorite_id": 4,
                "type": "INTEREST",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the first index from results `is_favorite` field value must be "is_favorite": "false" because not `exists()` the `favorite` relation, and in the second index is_favorite value must be "is_favorite": "true" because exists the relation.

My code to get this current json result I think that can be better... I'm noob in Laravel 5.0:

```
<?php
$Interests = \Reverse\Interest::with('category')
    ->where('status', '<>', 'DELETED')
    ->take($limit)
    ->offset($offset);

if (isset($allFilters['user'])) {
    $Interests->where('user_id', $allFilters['user']);
}

if (isset($allFilters['popularity'])) {
    $Interests->orderBy('popularity', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('expires_at', 'asc');
}

if (isset($allFilters['favorites'])) {
    if($Interests->with('favorite')->exists()) {
        $Interests->select(DB::raw('*, "true" AS is_favorite'));
    }
}

$responseContent = $Interests->get();
```

Reverse is my API namespace. The json return is made with application/json passed on Response Header:

```
<?php
// My Json Response Example
$Response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response();
$Response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$Response->setContent($Interests->get());
return $Response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel to add a custom field use `appends`attribute on your model, in this case:

```
<?php
protected $appends = ['is_favorite'];
```

And define an attribute accessor to your new attribute, in this case:

```
<?php
public function getIsFavoriteAttribute() {
    return $this->favorite()
        ->where('user_id', '=', $this->user_id)
        ->exists();
}
```

The favorite is a relation in my case:

```
<?php
public function favorite()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\Reverse\Favorite', 'favorite_id');
}
```

And finally my `favorites` filter is activated when satisfy the following condition this way:

```
<?php
if (isset($allFilters['favorites']) and filter_var($allFilters['favorites'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {
    $Interests->has('favorite');
}
```

I think that exists a better way to write this code... Can you explain if you know?

Comment: you define a new appended attribute, but never use it. In the filtering you still call on the raw relation, the addition of the appended attribute therefore (in the current code) is to no additional value.. Right?

Comment: @Luceos Yes, have a additional value: in my results now has a `is_favorite: true` or `false`. And this what I needed. The raw relation is just to get results  from a given `user` that has relation with a `favorite`. Exists a better way to write this code?